# To print Random no in Php each second

Tags: php

I want to generate random no in php per second and want to display that after clicking the generate button. Below is the code for same

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Random no Generator</title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
    </head>
    <?php
     if(isset($_GET['action'])=='submitfunc') {
     submitfunc();
     }else
    //show form
    ?>
    <body>
    <form action="?action=submitfunc" method="post">            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Generate" /></p>
            <p>
        </form>
    </body>

    <?php
        function submitfunc() {
    while(1){
      echo rand (5,10)."\n";
        sleep(1);    
     echo rand (25,50)."\n";
        sleep(1);        
    }   
}
    ?>
</html>
```

Edit:
I want to insert no in database perodicaly so need this to work via php

Comment: PHP runs on the server side, your code will time out as it never sends a response to the browser (endless loop). The simplest solution is to move the random number generation to javascript which runs in the browser.

Comment: My motive was to insert random no per second in database

Answer (score 0):

As said, PHP is a server-side scripting language. This [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pjzakwm/) may help.

```
<button id="gen">Generate</button>
<br/>
<div id="content">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var int1 = null;
var int2 = null;
var br = $('<br/>');
$("#gen").on('click', function(){
    int1 = setInterval(function(){
    var span = $('<span/>').text(~~(Math.random()*5+5));
    $("#content").append(span).append($('<br/>'));
  },2000);
  setTimeout(function(){
    int2 = setInterval(function(){
        var span = $('<span/>').text(~~(Math.random()*25+25));
        $("#content").append(span).append($('<br/>'));
    },2000);
  },1000);
});
</script>
```